I don't know how to make a custom function to change colours of numbers separated by "/"
I'm trying to make a custom function that will assign a different colour to each set of characters that are separated by "/", so that it would look like this:
different coloured text separated by slashes
The input will be three different numbers or groups of numbers in parenthesis as text, they are located in three different cells on a separate sheet like this:
Sheet Name: KH Utility



Sword
Shield
Staff




1
12
(32,24,90)


6
7
8


(12,38)
(1,24,57)
2



Then the output would be one string of these numbers/groups separated by a "/", located in a separate sheet called "KH Abilities, Magic, Summons WIP". The first will be red, in the middle will be green, and the last will be purple.
So far I have this:
function LVL(swLvl,shLvl,stLvl) {

// set text colours for each type
  var sword = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#C03636").build(); 
  var shield = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#43B040").build();
  var staff = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#7860C0").build();

// get sheet
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("KH Abilities, Magic, Summons WIP");

// turn inputs into array of characters
  var txt  = (`${swLvl}/${shLvl}/${stLvl}`);
  var array = [{}];
  array = txt.split();

// apply text colours based on character index
  const col = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText(array)
    .setTextStyle(0,array.indexOf('/'),sword) // ERROR illegal argument
    .setTextStyle(array.indexOf('/')+1, array.indexOf('/',2),shield)
    .setTextStyle(array.indexOf('/',2)+1, -1,staff)
    .build();
  return col;

}

When I try to use the function in a cell, I get an illegal argument error on line 20.
I have a feeling that I'm misunderstanding the way functions take multiple values. Any help would be appreciated.
